# Proving some theorems on the function index in Coq

Tags: coq

I’m trying to implement an index function in Coq. I’ve written this code:

```
Notation grid := (list nat).

Fixpoint index_aux (n : nat) (g : grid) (i : nat) : option nat :=
  match g with
  | [] => None
  | h :: t => if h =? n then Some i else index_aux n t (i + 1)
  end.

Definition index (n : nat) (g : grid) : option nat :=
  index_aux n g 0.
```

And I tried to prove some theorems about it. First, some simple lemmas:

```
Lemma index_nil : forall x, index x [] = None.
Proof. auto. Qed.

Lemma index_singleton : forall x, index x [x] = Some 0.
Proof.
  intros x. unfold index. simpl. destruct (x =? x) eqn:E.
  reflexivity. rewrite Nat.eqb_neq in E. contradiction.
Qed.

Lemma index_double : forall x, index x [x; x] = Some 0.
Proof.
  intros x. unfold index. simpl. destruct (x =? x) eqn:E.
  reflexivity. rewrite Nat.eqb_neq in E. contradiction.
Qed.
```

And now, I’m trying to prove a more general theorem:

```
Theorem index_in : forall l x, In x l -> exists n, index x l = Some n.
Proof.
  intros l x H. induction l.
  - destruct H.
  - destruct H as [-> | H].
    + exists 0. unfold index. simpl. destruct (x =? x) eqn:E.
      * reflexivity.
      * rewrite Nat.eqb_neq in E. contradiction.
    + apply IHl in H as [n Hn].
      unfold index. simpl. destruct (a =? x) eqn:E.
      * exists 0. reflexivity.
      *
```

I’ve two questions:

1. In the lemmas I’ve proved, are there better proofs? Or using `destruct` and `Nat.eqb_neq` is a good way to prove it?
2. I’ve no clues about what would be the following tactics to prove the theorem. I don’t know how to infer the existence of `n` from `In x l`. How can I do? (I’ll accept clues instead of a full answer. I still want to prove it on my own, but I’m stuck.)

Edit: Thanks to Pierre Courtieu’s answer, I proved my theorem. In case it would help someone, here is what I did:

```
Theorem index_in : forall l x, In x l -> exists n, index x l = Some n.
Proof.
  unfold index. intro l. generalize dependent 0. induction l.
  - intros _ _ [].
  - intros n x H. unfold index_aux. destruct (a =? x) eqn:E; fold index_aux.
    + exists n. reflexivity.
    + rewrite Nat.eqb_neq in E. destruct H as [->|H].
      * contradiction.
      * apply IHl with (n:=n + 1) in H. assumption.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 clues:

1. proving directly the property on `index` means you prove a property about `forall x l, index_aux x l 0` which is probably not general enough (you will end up needing something about `index_aux x l <something else>`). This is a general rule (even for pen and paper proofs): a proof by induction may need to be generalized for the induction to actually work.
   **Edit**: after trying it myself it turns out you do need something about the third argument of `index_aux` but you don't need to necessarily generalize your goal.
2. Be careful not to use the induction hypothesis too early.

**Edit**
3.And be also careful when you start your induction: try `intro l. induction l.` instead of `intros l x H. induction l` and compare induction hypothesis. You will see that `x` and `H` are quantified in the former case.

Comment: Thanks! I successfully proved the theorem. I’ve edited my first message to add the proof, in case it would help someone.